# Firebase: How do I update the same document that was created during a Gen 2 onDocumentCreated trigger event?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I can't get my trigger to update the same document that is being created. I printed out debug statements to the console and the error points to `documentData.set`. I've tried `document.ref.update`, `documentData.ref.set`, and `documentData.set`, but none of these work. The console shows these errors below. How do I update the same document that is being created during the create trigger?

```
document.ref.update:
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'update')

`documentData.ref.set:`

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')

`documentData.set:`

> TypeError: documentData.set is not a function

```
exports.onFriendAdded = onDocumentCreated(
  "users/{userDocID}/friends/{friendDocID}",
  async (event: any) => {
    const timestamp = getTimestamp();
    const document = event;
    const documentData = document.data.data();
    const moveOnToNextStep = documentData.moveOnToNextStep;
    let friendUID = documentData.uid;

    if (!moveOnToNextStep) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(myAppTag + " onFriendAdded started!");

    // If the friend uid = empty/null, update it
    if (friendUID == "" || friendUID == null) {
      console.log(myAppTag + " 1");
      const friendUsername = documentData.username;
      const friendInfo = await getUserInfo(1, friendUsername, "uid");
      console.log(myAppTag + " 2");

      if (friendInfo[0] == 1) {
        friendUID = friendInfo[2];
        console.log(myAppTag + " 3");

        // If sendFriendRequest = true, send a notification to the friend Doing
        // this here because updating the friendUID causes the onUpdate to fire
        // and don't want to double send the request.
        const sendFriendRequest = documentData.sendFriendRequest;

        if (sendFriendRequest) {
          console.log(myAppTag + " 4");
          const uid = event.params.userDocID;
          let username = "";

          const friendStatus = await getFriendStatus(uid, friendUID);
          console.log(myAppTag + " 5");

          if (friendStatus["returnVal"] == 0) {
            console.log(myAppTag + " 6");
            // If friend stat cant be found, dont send friend request
            console.log(
              myAppTag +
                " onFriendUpdated getFriendStatus returnVal is 0. Error: " +
                friendStatus["returnMsg"]
            );
            documentData.ref.set({
              sendFriendRequest: false,
              modifiedDate: timestamp,
            });
            return;
          }

          if (friendStatus["status"] == "0") {
            console.log(myAppTag + " 7");
            console.log(
              myAppTag +
                `onFriendUpdated getFriendStatus user B has blocked user
                A. status: ` +
                friendStatus["status"]
            );
            documentData.ref.set({
              sendFriendRequest: false,
              modifiedDate: timestamp,
            });
            return;
          }

          const userInfo = await getUserInfo(0, uid, "username");
          console.log(myAppTag + " 8");

          if (userInfo[0] == 1) {
            username = userInfo[2];
          }

          if (username == "" || username == null) {
            console.log(
              myAppTag +
                " onFriendAdded Error when getting user info: " +
                userInfo[1]
            );
            return;
          }
          console.log(myAppTag + " 9");
          const notifResult = await sendNotification(
            uid,
            username,
            friendUID,
            friendUsername,
            notifIDFriendRequest
          );
          console.log(myAppTag + " 10");

          if (notifResult[0] == 1) {
            console.log(myAppTag + " 11");
            documentData.set({ // ERROR POINTS HERE 
              sendFriendRequest: false,
              modifiedDate: timestamp,
            });
            console.log(myAppTag + " 11.1");
          } else {
            console.log(myAppTag + " 12");
            console.error(
              myAppTag +
                " onFriendAdded Error when sending the notification." +
                " uid: " +
                uid +
                " username: " +
                username +
                " friendUID: " +
                friendUID +
                " friendUsername: " +
                friendUsername +
                " returnVal: " +
                notifResult[0] +
                " returnMsg: " +
                notifResult[1]
            );
          }
        }
        console.log(myAppTag + " 12.1");
        documentData.ref.set({
          // Update "document" with the new data
          uid: friendUID,
          modifiedDate: timestamp,
        });
        console.log(myAppTag + " 13");
      } else {
        console.log(
          myAppTag +
            " onFriendAdded Error when getting friend info: " +
            friendInfo[1]
        );
        return; // The friend request (below) will not be sent
      }
    }
    console.log(myAppTag + " 14");
    await documentData.ref.set({
      moveOnToNextStep: false,
      modifiedDate: timestamp,
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using gen2 of Cloud Functions for Firebase, you're using the modular API - in which most functionality that calls the server is in top-level functions rather than methods on the objects.

If you check the reference docs of [`DocumentSnapshot` in the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md#firestoreondocumentcreated) you can confirm this, as it shows no `update` or `set` method.

To update the document, use the syntax from the documentation code sample on [updating a document with the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-modular-api_9):

```
import { doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const washingtonRef = doc(db, "cities", "DC");

// Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
  capital: true
});
```

Comment: Wait but this is for my cloud functions where I'm using Typescript

Comment: All JavaScript (as in the code sample I linked/included) is also valid typescript. What happened when you tried to use the `updateDoc` top-level function rather than call it as a method?